# How to add a specific year to the current one in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a function in javascript that adds the year 1993 + current_year and that inserts the result inside my `<span class = "title_25anos" id = "calculo_ano"> </ span>`

And this is my code.

```
<script>

    var ano_inicio = 1993;
    var ano_atual = getFullYear();

    var soma_ano = ano_inicio + ano_atual;

    document.getElementById("calculo_ano").innerHTML = "Há " . soma_ano . "anos com você";

</script>
```

Comment: You need to call `new Date().getFullYear()` to get current year, also fix the string concatenation

Comment: This isn't php. To add strings together, simply use "+", not "."

Comment: In javascript, strings get concatenated using `+`.  Try this:  `document.getElementById("calculo_ano").innerHTML = "Há " + soma_ano + "anos com você";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+`  to concatenate strings. To get the full year you have to have a date object first. For the date use `new Date()`

```js
var ano_inicio = 1993;
var ano_atual = new Date().getFullYear();
var soma_ano = ano_inicio + ano_atual;

document.getElementById("calculo_ano").innerHTML = "Há " + soma_ano + " anos com você";
```

```html
<span class="title_25anos" id="calculo_ano"> </ span>
```

Comment: Works even without the Number().

Comment: Why does my result appear with the - next to the 26?

THERE ARE -26 YEARS WITH YOU

Comment: what is your input?